# Trying to use Pagination(10 record each page) inside arrayOfObject

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data like this

```
    {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},...n{}]
   }

   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},...n{}] 
  }

  {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},...n{}] 
  }
  {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},...n{}]
  }
  
  {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},...n{}]
  }
```

What I'm trying to get here is exactly 10 record in each call which I'm getting when I have data like this (`assign_id` have exactly 1 record)

```
   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{}]
   }

   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{}]
   }
   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{}]
   }
   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{}]
   }
  {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{}]
  }
```

Problem statement

I want exactly 10 record in each call which includes assign_id count

Example, Let say i have something like this

```
   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
   }
   {
    _id:ObjectId("")
    c_id:ObjectId("")
    assign_id:[{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
   }
```

Now If i query i want only first record because it has exactly 10 record(`assign_id`: Has 10 Obj) set.

Current query

```
db.find(condition)
    .limit(parseInt(count))
     .skip(parseInt(skip))
```

I also try with this code

```
 db.find(condition,
    {assign_id:{$slice:[parseInt(skip),parseInt(count)]}})
```

But didn't work, Please help and pardon me for the lengthy explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `aggregate()` method,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `assign_id` array
- `$sort` by `_id` or you can specify field if you want another, order you can set as per your requirement 1(ascending), -1(descending),
- set `$skip` and `$limit`
- `$group` by `_id`, reconstruct `assign_id` field
- `$sort` by `_id`, you can set as per your requirement

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$assign_id" },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  { $skip: 0 },
  { $limit: 10 },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      c_id: { $first: "$c_id" },
      assign_id: { $push: "$assign_id" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GZuaO6klmAt)